# Why does my ice cream have ice crystals?

Tags: ice-cream

I put icecream mixture in freezer but after taking it out of freezer, I found ice crystals in it. What should be done to avoid ice crystals in icecream?

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1214/69382 and https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/42530/69382

Comment: If you include the the recipe you used, it will help to get a useful answer.

Comment: Include the method as well as the equipment you used.

Comment: I used the following recipe:                                                                              let cream and condensed milk to cool in refrigerator. After wards beat cream and condensed milk separately and then mix them. Add few drops of vanilla essence. then added choco chips  according to flavour. then at the end i put the mixture in air tight jar and let it cool for 12 hours